# Setting Comments property in Word document with OpenXML and C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I wrote a code that supposed to set the value of Comments property. It executes fine, but when I try to open the document thereafter, it displays the error.
Arguments: val is "EMA", and prop is "comments"

```
    public void SetProperty(string val, string prop)
    {
        // Define the namespaces for XPath queries.
        const string corePropertiesSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties";

        NameTable nt = new NameTable();
        XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
        nsManager.AddNamespace("cp", corePropertiesSchema);

        using (WordprocessingDocument wdPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open("C:\\Users\\Dev\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Doc1.docx", true))
        {
            // Get the core properties part (core.xml).
            CoreFilePropertiesPart corePropertiesPart = wdPackage.CoreFilePropertiesPart;

            // Load the XML in the part into an XmlDocument instance.
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
            xdoc.Load(corePropertiesPart.GetStream());
            
            // Find the Comments property.
            string searchString = "//cp:coreProperties/cp:comments";
            XmlNode commentsNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager);

            if (commentsNode != null)
            {
                // If the Comments property exists, update its value.
                commentsNode.InnerText = val;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the Comments property does not exist, create it.
                XmlElement modeElement = xdoc.CreateElement("cp", prop, corePropertiesSchema);
                modeElement.InnerText = val;
                xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(modeElement);
            }

            using (Stream stream = corePropertiesPart.GetStream())
            {
                // Save the changes to the core properties part.
                xdoc.Save(stream);

                searchString = string.Format("//cp:coreProperties/{0}", "cp:comments");

                XmlNode xNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager);
                if (!(xNode == null))
                {
                    string propertyValue = xNode.InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error upon opening the document:
[image]

I also ran OpenXML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office against this file, but it does not show much...
Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: You've got the Productivity toolkit. Another way you can use it is to create a Word document (in Word) without ant comments and save it.  Then add the comments (in Word) and save it with another filename. Then use the toolkit to _diff_ the two files. That should show you how to implement the feature (hopefully)

Comment: Well, I have been in the movie before... It is difficult to know what really affects the document and what not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the coreProperties Part at that level, you should be able to use this approach:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wdPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open("C:\\Users\\Dev\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Doc1.docx", true))
{
    wdPackage.PackageProperties.Description = "EMA";
    wdPackage.Save();
}
```

If you really need to manipulate the coreProperties Part directly, some things to notice:

Word's `Comments` property is mapped to the Dublin Core Property called `description` in the `http://purl.org/elements/1.1/` Namespace. (Confusing - Microsoft always had a property called `Comments` but not `Description`, the Dublin Core standard came later and clearly Microsoft decided to map Comments to description rather than allowing, for example, separate description and Comments properties). There isn't a "comments" property in the `cp` or `dc` namespaces AFAIK.

As far as I know, all the properties that you are *allowed* to put in the coreProperties part can be read/set via `PackageProperties`.

IMO you would have to refactor your existing code to cope with the fact that there are properties in more than one namespace. You'd need more than one namespace to do the search and set the value, and you'd need to decide whether to pass the property name and work out the namespace/prefix in the routine or pass the namespace as well. Also at the moment you're passing a property name but (for testing, I imagine) using a hardcoded name.

I started by  trying to modify your code to cope with this specific example but this line didn't find an existing description node (even with the correct namespace definitions and XPath) so I abandoned at that point. SO perhaps that would also need some more work.

```
XmlNode commentsNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager);
```

Comment: Many thanks. It threw exception  on my 1st document but then I fixed it and it worked on the others.